# That dood it, I dood it, meaning?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In 1958 James Brown introduced rapping with "That Dood It", and there's a movie from 1943 called "I Dood It"..  I assume "Dood" in this context is stand in for "Did". Is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tl;dr - It's a replacement for various forms of the verb "to do"

"I dood it" was a "catch phrase" for radio and film comedian [Red Skelton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Skelton), usually when performing as a bratty young boy often referred to as "The Mean Widdle Kid". He starred in that film, but not as the Mean Widdle Kid.

> If I dood it, I get a whupping...(pause) I dood it!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7dlZQQc0FEQ

It's a malaprop to indicate the immature speech pattern of a young child. It's a replacement for various forms of the verb "to do", so here it would translate as "If I do it, I'll be hit...(pause) I'll do it (or I'm going to do it)"

> The phrase was such a part of national culture at the time that, when
>   General Doolittle conducted the bombing of Tokyo in 1942, many
>   newspapers used the phrase "Doolittle Dood It" as a headline.
>   (via wiki, above)

In that case, it would translate as "Doolittle Did it"

In James Brown's song, it would translate as "that does it", as in "I've had enough"

Comment: Can you explain more why "that dood it" should be understood as meaning "that does it" rather than "that did it"?

Comment: Perhaps it's a tense issue - it could also mean "That did it", but in both cases, it's said to mean "I've had enough".  See also "That's it" or "That was it".

Comment: Might want to explicitly state that _widdle_ is another imitation of children’s speech, affecting _little_.

Answer (score 0):

It's because 'did' is an irregular verb in English and children sometimes mix those up, having learned the regular form first.

The past tense of 'do', if regular, would be to add -ed and say 'I do-ed it'. Then I guess it changes to 'dood' because 'doed' would probably be pronounced with a long O sound.

Comment: How is this different from the [other answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/454571/167396) that has already been accepted? Please make sure you read the other answers first and only post your own if you're providing a new solution or alternative angle. For further guidance, see [answer], and take the [Tour].